# What are these bugs skittering about the kitchen sink?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found a bunch of these around a kitchen sink in an apartment building in Toronto, Canada, in late October, 2019.

The bugs vary in size, but are all very tiny, less than one millimeter (the photos were taken with a macro lens, and still barely captured them).

They move very fast when they detect light changes, and hide in the crevices around the sink.

They die very easily when squashed.

**Edit:** Managed to shoot a larger, more photogenic specimen.

[image: new bug pic]

[image: new bug pic]

[image: new bug pic]

[image: bug pic 1]

[image: bug pic 2]

[image: bug pic 3]

Comment: Thankfully they are not cockroaches or bedbugs, but I cannot tell what they are from the pictures.

Comment: @KarlKjer Thanks for ruling those two out! I posted some better pictures, do they help narrow it down?

Comment: Yes, they define them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are springtails, order Collembola. Looks like they are in the family Entomobryidae. They are completely harmless. They don't bite, or spread disease. They often find their way into potted plants in people's homes. I'm not surprised that they are in your sink. Their small size makes them subject to desiccation. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomobryidae